# drupal 7 Wysiwyg add another item issue

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using latest version of drupal 7 with "wysiwyg editor tinyMCE"

I have created 1 content type "List" in that i am using "wysiwyg editor tinyMCE" with unlimited items.

Drupal 7 showing correct form with "add another item"

But when i fill the field and click "add another item" the filled value is despaired and showing "field empty error message"

I have debug lot and i found that when drupal requesting ajax call the submitting field value is empty. Means druapl wysiwyg module enable to capture the editor value.

This is not only with  tinyMCE also with another editor.

Any one know how to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found a work-around for that. (It's kinda silly, but it worked)

Before adding another item or re-ordering the items, just click `Disable rich-text` link. This won't cause your text to disappear.

Hope it works for you as it did for me... Muhammad.

Comment: I have used the development version of the wysiwyg editor and it's start working.